# Where to look for the library files after npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I am installing nodejs module(jasmine-ajax) in my local machine . I am expecting the entire libraries in git hub will be available in my local system.
But I am seeing only the main file in lib folder . Where the other dependend files will be placed.

npm install --save-dev jasmine-ajax

Executed the above command and I am not seeing all the files under source in my local view.

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you install a module like you did, it is placed in `node_modules` folder.
Running `npm install` is not getting all file from github repository, but from architecture that is pushed to npm. In the [jasmine-ajax github](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax), you can see a file called `.npmignore` which contains `src`. This file works like `.gitignore` files, `src` folder is excluded when he pushed is module to npm.

File in lib folder is generated from `src` folder files, so it contains all you want

Comment: Just to add some more details: To publish to npm, the maintainer (or the build bot) runs `npm publish` command, which 1) grabs all files in their workspace, 2) eliminates the files in `.npmignore` (or `.gitignore` if `.npmignore` is not there), 3) the resulting list of files is zipped and the ZIP is uploaded to npm repository as a new artifact; *npm is totally independent from github* (contrary to bower, which just contains metadata, and stuff is fetched usually from github)

Comment: Didn't know that `.gitignore` is used when there isn't `.npmignore`

Comment: it's documented here https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package :)

Answer (score 0):

When you launch a `npm install` without the `-g` flag the folder that you have to look for is `node_modules` in the path where you launched the command.

If you use `-g` flag it will be installed as a global module.

In your case the folder will be `node_modules/jasmine-ajax`.

[image: Path structure]

The fact that the `lib` folder contains only the `mock-ajax.js` file depends on the release they made on npm registry.

The `npm install` command **DOES NOT** clone the github repository, it downloads the release from the npm registry: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-ajax

Comment: Its not available , please try yourself

Comment: Picture with path structure attached

Answer (score 0):

*mock-ajax.js* file, in lib folder, represents the built library. You don't need to have all files in *src* when you download it from npm. You can use all *jasmine-ajax* features in this way:

> Install jasmine-ajax from NPM via npm install --save-dev jasmine-ajax;
>   you can then require('jasmine-ajax') inside your test-suite and access
>   it via the jasmine global.